# How would you do valuation of a bear put spread?

Tags: black-scholes

I have a CVR ([Contingent Value Right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingent_value_rights)) that behaves as a European long put and short put, with strike prices of 175 and 150. It is possible to value this instrument by Black and Scholes?

Comment: If the CVR behaves exactly like the portfolio of options you describe and the assumptions of Black Scholes apply to the stock in question, yes you should be able to approximate the value the CVR by using Black Scholes valuation of these options using arbitrage arguments.

Answer (score 1):

As you write, a bear put spread is a combination of going long a European put with a higher strike (here, 175) and short a European put with a lower strike (here, 150). Given the remaining parameters in Black-Scholes, i.e. the current underlying asset price $S$, the risk-free rate $r$, the volatility $\sigma$ and time to maturity $T$, you can simply value the options individually using the [Black-Scholes pricing formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Black%E2%80%93Scholes_formula).

The bear put spread is simply a portfolio of the two options, and hence its value is given by the value of the long put minus the value of the short put.